# Mintable ERC20 Token Smart Contarct

Tags: blockchain, polygon, solidity

I'm editing the ERC20 Contract from @OpenZeppelin to make it mintable you can see my progress here:

https://github.com/GameBully2K/Blockchain/blob/main/MintableERC20Token.sol

Now I'm facing a problem with the mint (line 685) function where I receive

`Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }`

Comment: Why don't you just import the template from like OpenZeppelin?

Comment: @burningalc in fact it is. It is the contract I said I'm editing I couldn't just import ERC20 and the other dependencies because I made some adjustments in them too . they are all there. because I flatenned it before commiting it